# woocommerce order prefix won't show up in export

Tags: woocommerce, export, prefix

The order numbers in our Woocommerce webshop need to have a certain prefix, so I added this code to the functions.php of our theme:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'webendev_woocommerce_order_number', 1, 2 );


function webendev_woocommerce_order_number( $oldnumber, $order ) {
    return 'WEB' . $order->id;
}
```

It works alright while viewing it on the frontend and backend, but when I try to export it with store export, download an invoice or anything else the prefix is not include. How can I force the prefix onto the order ID in exports, PDF's, etc?

Comment: You can't force a prefix on order ID as the order Id is the post ID that you can find on wp_post table. But you can use for example this plugin: Booster for Woocommerce or WooCommerce Sequential Order Numbers Pro.